# Error with parsing JSON using Json.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

I'm using this code to parse my JSON string and it throws an exception, the error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Myapp.exe Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

I have properly imported Json.Net and this very same code works in a different sub and parses just fine.

Here is my code:

```
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent)
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
For Each item As JProperty In results
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "response"
            Dim BatteryCharge As String
            For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                BatteryCharge = subitem("battery_level")
                MessageBox.Show(BatteryCharge)
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

The JSON string looks like this and for now I only need to fetch `battery_level` however if you could tell me how to include more if I need to that would be great.

`{
  "response": {
    "charging_state": "Complete",  // "Charging", ??
    "charge_to_max_range": false,  // current std/max-range setting
    "max_range_charge_counter": 0,
    "fast_charger_present": false, // connected to Supercharger?
    "battery_range": 239.02,       // rated miles
    "est_battery_range": 155.79,   // range estimated from recent driving
    "ideal_battery_range": 275.09, // ideal miles
    "battery_level": 91,           // integer charge percentage
    "battery_current": -0.6,       // current flowing into battery
    "charge_starting_range": null,
    "charge_starting_soc": null,
    "charger_voltage": 0,          // only has value while charging
    "charger_pilot_current": 40,   // max current allowed by charger & adapter
    "charger_actual_current": 0,   // current actually being drawn
    "charger_power": 0,            // kW (rounded down) of charger
    "time_to_full_charge": null,   // valid only while charging
    "charge_rate": -1.0,           // float mi/hr charging or -1 if not charging
    "charge_port_door_open": true
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to avoid using `JObject.Parse` approach and to instead deserialize it to a POCO, like so:

```
Sub Main
    Dim response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ResponseObject)("*your JSON string goes here*")

    Console.WriteLine("The battery level is " & response.response.battery_level)
End Sub

Public Class Response
    Public Property charging_state As String
    Public Property charge_to_max_range As Boolean
    Public Property max_range_charge_counter As Integer
    Public Property fast_charger_present As Boolean
    Public Property battery_range As Double
    Public Property est_battery_range As Double
    Public Property ideal_battery_range As Double
    Public Property battery_level As Integer
    Public Property battery_current As Double
    Public Property charge_starting_range As Object
    Public Property charge_starting_soc As Object
    Public Property charger_voltage As Integer
    Public Property charger_pilot_current As Integer
    Public Property charger_actual_current As Integer
    Public Property charger_power As Integer
    Public Property time_to_full_charge As Object
    Public Property charge_rate As Double
    Public Property charge_port_door_open As Boolean
End Class

Public Class ResponseObject
    Public Property response As Response
End Class
```

This also means that you can access and use the other properties later on in addition to `battery_level`.